# How to connect authentication system with spring boot jwt to React.js

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, jwt

I create a full-stack system written on the server side with JAVA and spring and a client side with react.js
I made a JWT system in order to connect to the system and also sign up.
The system works on the server side and I want to unify it into the appropriate component
And for some reason nothing works, it's important to emphasize that I'm brand new with react.js and this is the first project I create with react.js

this is the login.jsx component:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
import AuthService from '../services/AuthService';
import "./Login.css";

class login extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            username: '',
           password: '',
        }
        this.signin = this.signin.bind(this);
    }

    signin(){
        let loginRequest = {username: this.state.username, password: this.state.password};

        AuthService.signin(loginRequest).then(res=>{
            this.props.history.push('/home');
        });
                console.log('employee => ' + JSON.stringify(loginRequest));

    }

    changeUserNameHandler= (event) => {
                this.setState({username: event.target.value});
            }
            
     changePasswordHandler= (event) => {
                 this.setState({password: event.target.value});
            }

    render() {
        return (
          <section className="container">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-md-6">
                <div className="card">
                  <form className="box">
                    <h1>Login</h1>
                    <p className="text-muted"> Please enter your User Name and Password!</p>                  
                            <input onChange={this.changeUsertNameHandler} autoComplete="off" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"/>                        
                             <input onChange={this.changePasswordHandler} autoComplete="off" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/> 
                     
                          <a className="forgot text-muted" href="#">Forgot password?</a>
                          <input onClick={this.signin} type="submit" name="" value="Login" href="#"/>
                      <div className="col-md-12">
                        <ul className="social-network social-circle">
                            <li><a href="#" className="icoFacebook" title="Facebook"><i className="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" className="icoGoogle" title="Google +"><i className="fab fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                      <div className="form-group">
                          <div className="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      
                  </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
        );
    }
}
export default login;
```

and this is the AuthController(java spring):

```
package com.example.coffeedemo.Controller;

import com.example.coffeedemo.model.ERole;
import com.example.coffeedemo.model.Role;
import com.example.coffeedemo.model.User;
import com.example.coffeedemo.repository.RoleRepository;
import com.example.coffeedemo.repository.UserRepository;
import com.example.coffeedemo.requests.LoginRequest;
import com.example.coffeedemo.requests.SignupRequest;
import com.example.coffeedemo.response.JwtResponse;
import com.example.coffeedemo.response.MessageResponse;
import com.example.coffeedemo.security.JwtUtils;
import com.example.coffeedemo.service.UserDetailsImpl;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/")
public class AuthController {

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder encoder;

    @Autowired
    JwtUtils jwtUtils;

    @PostMapping("/signin")
    public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(@RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {
        System.out.println(userRepository.findByUsername(loginRequest.getUsername()));

        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getUsername(), loginRequest.getPassword()));

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        String jwt = jwtUtils.generateJwtToken(authentication);
        
        UserDetailsImpl userDetails = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();
        List<String> roles = userDetails.getAuthorities().stream()
                .map(item -> item.getAuthority())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponse(jwt,
                                                 userDetails.getId(), 
                                                 userDetails.getUsername(), 
                                                 userDetails.getEmail(), 
                                                 roles));
    
    }

    @PostMapping("/signup")
    public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser(@RequestBody SignupRequest signUpRequest) {
        if (userRepository.existsByUsername(signUpRequest.getUsername())) {
            return ResponseEntity
                    .badRequest()
                    .body(new MessageResponse("Error: Username is already taken!"));
        }

        if (userRepository.existsByEmail(signUpRequest.getEmail())) {
            return ResponseEntity
                    .badRequest()
                    .body(new MessageResponse("Error: Email is already in use!"));
        }

        // Create new user's account
        User user = new User(signUpRequest.getUsername(),
                             signUpRequest.getEmail(),
                             encoder.encode(signUpRequest.getPassword()));

        Set<String> strRoles = signUpRequest.getRole();
        System.out.println(strRoles);
        Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

        if (strRoles == null) {
            Role userRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_USER)
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
            roles.add(userRole);
        } else {
            strRoles.forEach(role -> {
                switch (role) {
                case "admin":
                    Role adminRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_ADMIN)
                            .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
                    roles.add(adminRole);

                    break;
                case "mod":
                    Role modRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_MODERATOR)
                            .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
                    roles.add(modRole);

                    break;
                default:
                    Role userRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_USER)
                            .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
                    roles.add(userRole);
                }
            });
        }

        user.setRoles(roles);
        userRepository.save(user);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new MessageResponse("User registered successfully!"));
    }
}
```

In the current situation, when I try to connect nothing happens ..
even printing to console.log..

Would appreciate help
Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

Change your `input` to a normal `<button onClick={this.signin}>Login</button>`.

**edit** and if that doesn't help, show us your `AuthService.signin` function

Comment: Hi, Thanks for youe help
but im getting 401(i belive its somthing that connect to the spring secutiry
"Unauthorized error: Full authentication is required to access this resource" (from the server)

Comment: Are you getting it on a sign in attempt? If so, make sure that you're not securing the "/api/signin" endpoint at SecurityConfig.